# Spring AOP for non-Beans classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am trying to learn Spring AOP, and as I understand, it works via proxies, and one can apply aspects to beans only, working with proxies instead of with beans directly.
So I have

```
@Controller
public class CMSHelloWorld {

    String message;

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        if (message == null || message.equals("")) {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");
            MessageBean messageBean = (MessageBean) context.getBean("simpleServiceProxy");
            message = messageBean.getMessage();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
//getters & setters omitted
}
```

Also I have very simple bean:

```
public class MessageBean {
    String message;
    //getters & setters omitted
}
```

And config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="simpleServiceBean" class="com.beans.MessageBean">
        <property name="message" value="Hello" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="simpleControllerBean" class="com.controller.CMSHelloWorld">
    </bean>

    <bean id="doBeforeMethodBean"
        class="com.demshin.advice.DoBeforeMethod" />

    <bean id="simpleServiceProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="target" ref="simpleServiceBean" />
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>doBeforeMethodBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="simpleControllerProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="target" ref="simpleControllerBean" />
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>doBeforeMethodBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It works fine for the methods of `MessageBean`, and obviously it doesn't work for the methods of `Controller` as this class addressed directly, not via its proxy.
So what is the correct way to apply AOP to Controller then?

Comment: Why do you have this in another `ApplicationContext` which you initialize **within** the controller? Why isn't your AOP part of the web application's `ApplicationContext`'?

Comment: I am new in Spring, so I'm afraid I don't understand your point, sorry. Could you elaborate or point me to some tutorial clearly stating the correct way?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/)'s the Spring documentation.

Comment: Thank you, but still maybe you can spend some time for me and explain briefly what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you don't create an application context when a request arrives to your controller. In the simplest case, the application context is loaded at application startup, and when loading process has finished, you have all your beans correctly created, configured, proxied, and injected, etc.

Comment: thanks, i will read more about that and return.

Answer (score 0):

A Spring `ApplicationContext` is self contained.

Your `@Controller` bean is executing in a `WebApplicationContext` which was created through your web application, either by a `ContextLoaderListener` or a `DispatcherServlet` (or Spring boot).

When you send a request and the `DispatcherServlet` chooses your `@Controller` bean to handle it, your `helloWorld` method creates a **new** `ApplicationContext`, completely independent from the web application one, with its own beans.

The bean declared there

```
<bean id="simpleControllerBean" class="com.controller.CMSHelloWorld">
</bean>`
```

has absolutely no relation to the bean handling the request.

If you want AOP advice to apply to the bean handling the request, define your AOP logic in the web application's `ApplicationContext`.